# sandbox vs . production environment

Tags: iphone, push-notification

Would it be completly wrong to develop your app against the production servers? I know the token are different and there and not so many servers in the sandbox env. but that't it right?

Cheers

Comment: Please be more clear, because I think many people don't understand anything about your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically Apple is not stopping you from developing app against the production APNS servers, but its not recommended.
You should do it only if are very sure that you wont bombard the production servers.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the issue is that if you work in a team with many developers (some of which you maybe don't trust 100%), You don't want to let the developers use the production certificates so that if things go wrong with one of them he will not have the data required to send messages to you production clients.